# Can I answer my own question with another question?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, self-answer

I already read questions/answers here about answering your own question and already know it is **okay** to do so.

But what actually happened is that I found the answer in another Stack Overflow question that I didn't find prior to asking.

My question is structured differently and could give others a different approach to the subject. But the answer is virtually the same as the other question I found.

1. Should I delete my question? (I don't mind doing it if it is flagged as a duplicate)
2. Should I answer my own question with a link to the other one (whose answer nails it)?
3. Should I do anything else, like wait for someone to re-answer on the subject?

#### Link References

1. [Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169278/irb-and-ruby-object-model)
2. [Link to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045195/understanding-ruby-class-and-ancestors-methods/19045339#19045339)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Close it as a dupe?

Comment: Hi, off topic but can I ask for a favor? Can you please try upvote a comment that was not made on your own question? Just pick a random comment, e.g. [from here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216577/152859) and see if you can upvote. I try to verify if comment upvote is granted on 15 or 50 rep points. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close (or flag for closure, if you don't have enough rep) to close your question as a duplicate of the other question that you found.  It will still stick around as a pointer to the duplicate question, so it can (potentially) make it easier to find that other question, but it also ensures that there is still one canonical place where all of the answers to that question can be found, rather than scattering the answers throughout several questions, or duplicating content.

Comment: The community flagged it for me. I'm impressed with the community here. And thank you for you answer. Concise and informative.